# Приложение отклонено READ_SMS Play Market

Tags: java, android, playmarket

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке выложить приложение в Play Market, приходит отказ. В файле манифеста прописано

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Добавил политику конфиденциальности : https://github.com/victor30608/Manager_Android/blob/master/privacy_policy.html
ссылка на проект https://github.com/victor30608/Manager_Android/

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку

Comment: Они же (Маркет) предупреждали всех, что пермишины чтения смс и доступа к журналу вызовов больше нельзя юзать,  как и соответсвующие фичи. Вы рассылки не читаете?

Comment: @OlegA , я впервые пытаюсь выложить приложение в Play Market.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вкратце Google ужесточил политику разрешений и теперь только стандартные приложения Android могут использовать такие разрешения как:

***CALL_LOG***

```
READ_CALL_LOG
WRITE_CALL_LOG
PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
```

***SMS***

```
SEND_SMS
RECEIVE_SMS
READ_SMS
RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH
RECEIVE_MMS
```

Google делал рассылку на почту разработчиков и предупреждал что у вас есть 90 дней для реализации новых правил. Ну и конечно предложили свой сервис **SMS Retriever API** 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview

Comment: Теперь фонариков на маркете поубавится :D